# How to eliminate extra space on the bottom of the page (WP theme)

Tags: html, css

I am working on a Wordpress theme for a friend, and for some reason I couldn't pin-point, there's an extra space on the bottom of the page. My container divs have 100% height, I added red & blue borders just so the boundaries are visible.

My structure is as follows:

[image]

dark grey is the mother container in which there are two child containers (medium grey), inside the right child container, there's another container (light grey)

Anyone with a fresh pair of eyes could help me fix this?

**the website**
http://vedroelcitra.com/blog/

**the CSS**
http://vedroelcitra.com/blog/wp-content/themes/nyan/style.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove padding top and bottom from `#sidebar`. that is putting extra space beneath the sidebar.

Try this:-

```
#sidebar {
border: 1px solid green;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 19%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0 2% 0 2%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @cogsmos. Guessing thats what OP is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow discourages links.  It's better to put the code in the question (because inevitably, the content in the link will change).

Your problem is with your `#sidebar` element (the left container).  You need to change the padding to `0 2%` for example, to remove the padding that is in addition to the 100% height, as you say.  So, to clarify, change your `#sidebar` padding from `2%` to `0 2%`.

`0 2%` means 0 on the top and bottom, and 2% on the sides.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `height:100%` from `#sidebar` ...